# Sum/Product of two Infinitely Divisible matrices is Infinitely Divisible?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, matrix-calculus, positive-semidefinite

**Definition -** An entry wise non-negative matrix is said to be ID if $A^{or} = [a_{ij}^r]$ is PSD (positive semi definite) for all $r \geq 0$ i.e r being a non-negative real no. 
I need to prove or disprove that : 
 If A and B are ID matrices  \
 a ) then A+B is an ID matrix 
 b) and if AB = BA(so that AB becomes hermitian) then AB is also ID.

I have some example of ID matrices which are min(i,j), gcd(i,j), any 2-square PSD matrix etc. After taking these examples it seems the result is positive. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to make it clear to me:  Your $A^{or}$ is the matrix whose $ij$ entry is the $r$th power of the $ij$ entry of $A$?  Or is matrix multiplication somehow involved in the definition of ID?

Comment: yes, it's the $r$'th power of $ij$'th entry like you said.

Comment: Hi @veersinghpanwar did you find a solution to this in the end? Is the product of a PSD and an infinitely divisible matrix also infinitely divisible?